# lite value on full and lite apps

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

I have an app that has both the full and the lite versions (including the in app purchase) the thing is that when I buy the app, the lite version loads all the full things, but when I close the app and open it again, It doesnt load the full menu and all the stuff including the full version.
As i am modifying a code that someone else do, i dont understand too much how to set some things (like levels, icons, or special things that buying the app do) to don't appear on the lite but yes in the full.

I found this in the app delegate:

```
-(void)setLite:(bool)value
{
    lite = value;
    [self saveUserDefaults];
}

-(void)loadUserDefaults
{
    NSUserDefaults * prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if(prefs)
    {
        wasExecuted = [[prefs objectForKey:@"wasExecuted"] boolValue];
        lite = [[prefs objectForKey:@"lite"] boolValue];

        if(!wasExecuted)
            lite = YES;
//        if(wasExecuted)
//            lite = NO;
    }
}

-(void)saveUserDefaults
{
    NSUserDefaults * prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if(prefs)
    {
        [prefs setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:executed] forKey:@"executed"];
        [prefs setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:lite] forKey:@"lite"];
    }
}
```

and this is how it is used on a switch (for example):

```
case 7:
            if(appDelegate.lite)
            {                
                [self showSubInfo:@"xxxxx.png" btnClosePos:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
//                [self xxxxxlite];
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"xxxx");
                storyBoardPage7 *xxxxx = [[xxxxx alloc]init];
                xxxx.modalTransitionStyle = MODAL_TRANSITION_STYLE;
                [rootViewController xxxx animated:YES];
                [xxxx release];
            }
```

This is the method that triggers when the IAP was succesfull:

```
-(void) changeMenuToFull {
    NSLog(@"Buy complete");

    [appDelegate setLite:NO];

       [self removeLiteMenu];
       [self loadFullMenu];
}
```

but i don't know why it doesnt save the menu when closing it...

thanks for reading.

Comment: Bear in mind: `2.9
Apps that are "beta", "demo", "trial", or "test" versions will be rejected`

Comment: @JamesWebster Nevermind that. It's all ok on my app.

Comment: is wasExecuted ever set to TRUE? If not, lite is always overwritten in your loadUserDefaults function ... PLUS: the saveUserDefaults functions misses a [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize] call to persist the defaults.

Comment: @TheEye Sorry, I just read this. Can you please explain this more in an answer? I think you have what I need!

Comment: when you change the user defaults, they are only changed "in memory", so when you stop the application and restart, the change is lost. To persist them to disk, you have to call [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize] after changing them, in your case at the end of the saveUserDefaults function

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the dev is saving a bool value in user defaults on whether to load the lite version or full version.

The only thing I see which might be going wrong with this code is that `wasExecuted` is being returned as `NO` which is why `lite` is set to `YES` and thus the lite version is being loaded.

Can you check what the value of wasExecuted is once IAP has been done and you reopen the app?

Comment: I don't know why, the sandboxing is not working for me. I will keep trying; but anyways I guess it will return NO. Notice that the `//if(wasExecuted)
//            lite = NO;` is commented

Comment: The comment shouldn't make a difference because if the purchase was successful, you are anyways setting lite to NO and storing it in the user defaults. Why is wasExecuted used anyway?

Comment: I really don't know why the other developer use it, but I guess you are right. What should I do? I take off the comments on the if?

Comment: First check why it is used and if the value is set correctly in all cases. Probably they forgot to update the value?

Comment: I will check it, and tell you.

Comment: Finnally I have tested it, and it returned FALSE.

Comment: aaargh - of course it returns false ... one, like I wrote above, you are not calling synchronize on the user defaults when saving them, and even if you would, you are saving the executed value to the key "executed", but you read the value from the key "wasExecuted" - the value of the key "wasExecuted" is never set and always will be false.

Comment: @TheEye So, I should include or uncomment this?
//if(wasExecuted)
//            lite = NO;

Comment: no, you should use the "wasExecuted" key in both functions - saving and reading user defaults, not "executed" as key name in the load function. And add [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] synchronize] at the end of the saveDefaults function.

Comment: @TheEye Oh I get it, so I should incude that If on the saveUserDefaults like the developer did it on the loadUserDefaults. I will test it right now.

Comment: @TheEye The `if(wasExecuted)` that I added in the saveUserDefaults should return `lite=YES`?

Answer (score 0):

This is what the code should look like:

```
-(void)setLite:(bool)value
{
    lite = value;
    [self saveUserDefaults];
}

-(void)loadUserDefaults
{
    NSUserDefaults * prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if(prefs)
    {
        wasExecuted = [[prefs objectForKey:@"wasExecuted"] boolValue];
        lite = [[prefs objectForKey:@"lite"] boolValue];

        if(!wasExecuted)
            lite = YES;
//        if(wasExecuted)
//            lite = NO;
    }
}

-(void)saveUserDefaults
{
    NSUserDefaults * prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if(prefs)
    {
        [prefs setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:executed] forKey:@"wasExecuted"];
        [prefs setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:lite] forKey:@"lite"];
        [prefs synchronize];
    }
}
```

Now if lite was set to YES in the user defaults it will be YES after you call loadUserDefaults.